# How to update my svn branch?

Tags: svn, branch

I created a branch one week ago and did some change. Then I committed and merged my branch into the trunk.

Now, I want to change some code again. I use "svn update" to update the trunk to the latest version. My problem is when I use "svn switch" to switch back to my branch, it will automatically change everything back to the old version, which was not I want.

One way to solve it is by creating a new branch. But I have to create a new issue in order to creating a new branch. Is there any way to update my old branch to the latest while not create a new branch? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to merge changes from the trunk back to your branch.  Think of it this way: you changed stuff on your branch and told the trunk about it. Meanwhile, other people were doing stuff on trunk. They need to tell your branch about it now.

But according to another way of thinking, your branch does not need to exist anymore. You made the changes, you sent them back to trunk: the lifetime of your branch is done. You continue on trunk. You only create a new branch if you expect to be some significant amount of time developing the new features.